# CS50 filter-more: Edges produces a bright image

Tags: c, cs50

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    float gxR, gxG, gxB;
    float gyR, gyG, gyB;
    int index;

    int gx[3][3] ={{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int gy[3][3] ={{-1, -2, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2 , 1}};

    printf("%i %i\n", gx[0][0], gy[0][0]);

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            gxR = gxG = gxB = 0;
            gyR = gyG = gyB = 0;

            for(int y2 = -1; y2 < 2; y2++)
            {
                index = 0;

                for(int x2 = -1; x2 < 2; x2++)
                {

                   if(y + y2 < 0 || y + y2 > height - 1 || x + x2 < 0 || x + x2 > width - 1)
                   {
                        continue;
                   }

                   gxR = gxR + (image[y+y2][x+x2].rgbtRed * gx[y2+1][x2+1]);
                   gxG = gxG + (image[y+y2][x+x2].rgbtGreen * gx[y2+1][x2+1]);
                   gxB = gxB + (image[y+y2][x+x2].rgbtBlue * gx[y2+1][x2+1]);
                   gyR = gyR + (image[y+y2][x+x2].rgbtRed * gy[y2+1][x2+1]);
                   gyG = gyG + (image[y+y2][x+x2].rgbtGreen * gy[y2+1][x2+1]);
                   gyB = gyB + (image[y+y2][x+x2].rgbtBlue * gy[y2+1][x2+1]);

                }
            }

            float red = fmin(round(sqrt((gxR * gxR) + (gyR * gyR))), 255);
            float green = fmin(round(sqrt((gxG * gxG) + (gyG * gyG))), 255);
            float blue = fmin(round(sqrt((gxB * gxB) + (gyB * gyB))), 255);

            temp[y][x].rgbtRed = red;
            temp[y][x].rgbtGreen = green;
            temp[y][x].rgbtBlue = blue;
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = temp[i][j];
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

I am going through CS50 free course, I am currently on problem set 4 filter-more.

https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/more/

The issue I am having is the last filter where I am supposed to implement edge filtering using sobel operators, but the image I am producing is far too bright.

I can't seem to find the logical error I am making here, any help would be very much appreciated.

[image]
[image: Original image]

Comment: int gy[3][3] ={{-1, -2, -1}  ...   you have 1 instead of the -1 in your code. Good luck.